# how to add queries from 2 diferrent form using php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I want to make a cofirm command page, that user after select the produse he cofirm the comand using the CONFIRM FORM, then to redirection him to the cofirm page, where he must write their dates to cofirm the command(the user dates)

So after i have a array in page cart.php

```
$cofirmaComanda .='<form  action="cofirma_comanda.php" method="post">
        <input name="prettotal"  type="hidden" value="'. $pricetotal .'">
         <input name="produseID"  type="hidden" value="'. $item_id .'">
         <input name="produseNume"  type="hidden" value="'. $product_name .'">
         <input name="size"  type="hidden" value="'. $my_ArraySize .'">
         <input name="cantitate"  type="hidden" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] .'">
         <input name="produse"  type="hidden" value="'. $item_id .'">
          <input type="submit" name="CofirmaComanda" value="cofirma_comanda"></form>';
```

then the cofirm page

```
<?php 
session_start(); // Start session first thing in script
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
?>
<?php
$pretTotal = $_POST["prettotal"];
$PRODUSE = $_POST["produseID"];
$produseNume = $_POST["produseNume"];
$size = $_POST["size"];
$cantitate = $_POST["cantitate"];
echo "ID: ".$PRODUSE."<br>";
echo "nume produs selectat: ".$produseNume." <br>";
echo $pretTotal." preata total in LEI<br>";
echo $cantitate." cantitate<br>";
echo $size." dimensiune<br>";


// Filter Function -------------------------------------------------------------------
function filterFunction ($var) { 
    $var = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($var));
    $var = str_replace("/", "\\\\", $var);
    $var = preg_replace("~/~", "\\\\", $var);
    return $var; 
} 
$pretTotal = filterFunction($pretTotal);
$PRODUSE = filterFunction($PRODUSE);
$produseNume = filterFunction($produseNume);
$size = filterFunction($size);
$cantitate = filterFunction($cantitate);

    if(isset($_SESSION["sumbitDateClienti"])){
    $nume = $_POST["nume_client"];
$comanda = 'IDprodus: '.$PRODUSE.' / produseNume: '.$produseNume.' / cantitate: '.$cantitate.' / dimensiune: '.$size.' ';
     $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT  comanda (pret_comanda, comanda) VALUES (?, ?)");
    // TODO check that $stmt creation succeeded
    // "s" means the database expects a string
         $stmt->bind_param("ss", $pretTotal, $comanda);
         $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->execute())            {
        echo "<strong>succes</strong> pagina a fost creata\n titlu: n<a href='admin_index_istorie.php'><strong>Inapoi la pagina de modificare istorie</strong></a>";

        }
        else {
            echo "eroare";
            }
    $stmt->close();
    }
    else{
    echo "completeaza forum pentru a finaliza comanda";
    }
?>
```

the form on the cofirm page

```
<form action=""   method="post">
nume: <input name="nume_client" type="text">
<input type="hidden" name="prettotal" value="<?php echo $_POST['prettotal'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="produseID" value="<?php echo $_POST['produseID']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="produseNume" value="<?php echo $_POST['produseNume']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cantitate" value="<?php echo $_POST['cantitate']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?php echo $_POST['size']; ?>">
<input  type="submit" name="sumbitDateClienti" value="ok">
</form>
```

I am stucking in this problem because if i put a name on the field is noting doing, doesnt insert the query in the database, and also doesnt give me the else return with the error

Comment: this `if(isset($_SESSION["sumbitDateClienti"])){` should be `if(isset($_POST["sumbitDateClienti"])){`. Or do you ever set this Session-Var where we can't see it?

Comment: Indeed thank you, i didnt realise , but now is work